# changing single list items value in dictionary with multi-values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

this is the following

```
data = {"A": [["a", 4, 4.50],["b", 5, 3.50]], "C": [["c", 7, 27.00],["d", 1, 7.99]]}
```

if I want to change only 3rd items of 2nd value of key "C" (["d", 1, (**7.99**)])

into like

```
date =  {"A": [["a", 4, 4.50],["b", 5, 3.50]], "C": [["c", 7, 27.00],["d", 1, 5.25]]}
```

how would you update the value inside of 2D list?

Comment: ...`data['C'][1][2] = 5.25` and then `date = data`

Comment: 2D lists are just lists inside lists. When using the first index, you enter the outer list and using the second index you enter the inner list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean:

```
data['C'][1][2] = 5.25
```

so what this does is get the key `'C'`, gets the second list and then the third item of that list.

Then I suppose you would just do `date = data` if that isn't a typo.